# Замена глагольных словосочетаний глаголами

Tags: лексика

В интернете наткнулся на задание. Надо заменить глагольные словосочетания глаголами.

**Ведутся работы по поиску** способа выращивания быстрорастущих деревьев, богатых углеводами.

Честно говоря, на ум ничего не приходит. Глагол "работает" здесь не подходит. Может "ищут", но и здесь, не подходит по значению,это уже не однокоренной глагол.

Ср.: напр.: оказывать содействие - содействовать.

Есть какие-н. версии?

Comment: Может, "про[из]водится поиск"?

Comment: grizzl, нужен глагол. Иначе подобрать синоним легко.

Comment: Разрабатывается способ...

Comment: Как вариант: "Ищутся способы..."

Comment: Выявляется; определяется; находится; предлагается; выбирается; утверждается; изыскивается.

Comment: slava1987, я почти тоже самое подумал.Только не ищутся, а ищут. Загвозда в том, что нужен однокоренной глагол по условиям задания. Поэтому возник  вопрос.

Comment: Серж, так я предложил вариант с "ищутся", поскольку он однокоренной с "поиском", представленном в сочетании "Ведутся работы по **поиску**"...

Comment: А чем разрабатывается не подходит? Это и есть работа, включающая проведение и поиск. Разрабатывать можно способы, методы, варианты.

Comment: slava, мне ваш вариант нравится.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец, "разрабатывать поиск"?  А по-моему, это неграмотное ввражение.

Comment: Ну какой же поиск?

Comment: Разработка метода, способа включает поиск вариантов и подразумевает продолжительное действие, проведение. Вот вам и "ведутся", и "поиски", и однокоренное слово к подлежащему "работа". Три в одном

Comment: Самый первый мой комментарий из двух слов: разраб. способ.

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: Александр Стрелец, все предложенные варианты здесь хорошие.Но в задании было выделено все словосочетание. Который нужно было заменить олним словом. Постараюсь сегодня скрин зщкдания предоставить.

Comment: Ну так я в своем ответе и в комментариях тоже отмечаю, что всё сочетание нужно заменить.

Comment: Заменить одним глаголом. Что крайне трудно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Большой список комментариев побудил написать ответ.

**Ведутся работы по поиску**. Глагольное сочетание нужно заменить одним однокоренным глаголом.
К какому слову подобрать глагол?

**Проводится** способ — не подходит.
**Ищется** способ — может быть, но, по-моему, не звучит в предложении научного характера.
Остаётся слово "работа" —  костяк (подлежащее) в первоначальном высказывании.

[**Разрабатывать**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) — глагол несовершенного вида, т. е. подразумевает продолжительность действия, подходит на замену "ведутся".
Его значения: *создавать, творчески воплощать, исследовать*.

Исследование, создание включают и поиск. Разрабатывать можно методы, способы, варианты и пр.

[**Способ**](http://tolkslovar.ru/s11010.html). 1. Образ действий, приём, метод для осуществления, достижения чего-л.

**Итог:**

*Разрабатывается способ выращивания быстрорастущих деревьев, богатых углеводами.*

P. S. Моё видение решения вопроса родилось спонтанно, ответ казался простым. Но, прочитав мнение других, практически сразу пришло чёткое понимание, что они правы. Я сделал акцент на подлежащем ***работа***, а главное с точки зрения смысла всё-таки ***поиск***. Верно, что глагол *разрабатывать* далеко не всегда значит *искать* (а в отрыве от контекста, можно сказать, и вовсе никогда не значит).

Comment: Да, наверное вы правы.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Серж,  а разве семантика сообщения при  такой замене  сохраняется? РАЗРАБОТАТЬ 2. Тщательно, во всех деталях подготовить.  Разработать новую технологию.  Но ведь искать способы - это не  обязательно разрабатывать их, можно купить нужную технологию, так многие и делают.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидная замена: **ведутся работы по поиску — ищутся**.

**Поиск и искать** — явно однокоренные слова. В нацкорпусе 35 примеров с глаголом *ищутся*, вот один из них:

*Бывает так, что у компании возникает нехватка средств. **Ищутся** разные способы, перебираются варианты.*

Вот научный стиль: В это же время осуществляется переход от синтаксиса к семантике языка, **ищутся** пути соединения синтаксиса и семантики... [С. С. Неретина(2006)]

Вообще говоря, замена глагольных сочетаний глаголами — один из основных принципов современного информационного стиля. В книгах по этой теме такие примеры приводятся целыми списками.

Answer (score 2):

Из моего комментария:

> Как вариант: *"**Ищутся** способы..."*

"Как вариант" — это потому, что угадать ответ, задуманный авторами задания, не всегда возможно. Может, нужно было сохранить ед. число слова "способ"?

Тогда ответом было бы: *"**Ищется** способ..."*

Оба сочетания возможны. См. примеры в Гугл-книгах:

**"Ищутся способы"** — https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%98%D1%89%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGs76RkpzpAhUNr4sKHcPODh4Q_AUoAXoECAoQCQ&biw=1206&bih=601

**"Ищется способ"** — https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%98%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiiqpO3kpzpAhVsxosKHe-bA84Q_AUoAXoECAcQCQ&biw=1206&bih=601

**P.S.**

Меня бы очень удивило, если бы задумывался ответ *"**Разрабатывается** способ…"*. Правильным он был бы, если бы в условии требовалась замена на глагол сочетания *"В**едется разработка** способа"*… У нас же пока — только ***поиск***...

**P.P.S.**

(Спустя два дня...)

Несколько слов относительно принятого Сержем варианта.

*"**Ведутся работы по поиску** способа…"* — это, на мой взгляд,  не то же самое, что *"**Разрабатывается** способ…"* (как минимум, не всегда то же самое).

Вполне может быть, что способы эти уже существуют. И требуется  только, порывшись в книгах, диссертациях или интернете, разыскать их.

Чтобы было более понятно, о чём идёт речь, приведу такой пример:

***Ведутся работы по поиску*** месторождений полезных ископаемых.

Каким глаголом можно было бы заменить сочетание ***"Ведутся работы по поиску"***?

Comment: slava1947, в задании было выделено все словосочетание.